how to fix error module module not found?
Error [ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND]: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\npm-cache_npx\125ee17d583c4e03\node_modules\commander\esm.mjs' imported from C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\npm-cache_npx\125ee17d583c4e03\node_modules\shadcn-ui\dist\index.js
Did you mean to import commander/index.js?
please what is the issue here , this happens anytime i want to install shadcn
